# Не понимаю смысл кодировок

Tags: javascript, node.js, строки, кодировка, хранение-данных

1. Когда в **языке программирования** **(например javascript)** мы пишем что-то в строку или добавляем символ **(a = ''; a += 'b';)**, то в какой кодировке она хранится в самой памяти ?
2. Зачем указывать кодирвоку при открытии текстового файла **(Node js)** если это просто набор бит?
3. Зачем при сохранении указывать кодировку? Может чтоб битовая последовательность из памяти сохранилась именно в этой кодировке ? Но это не так. Ведь если я напишу строку и поставлю кодировку hex **(Опять же я про node js)** он ничего не сделает пустой файл. Даже hex edit показывает что там просто ничего нет. Как это всё работает? Просто помогите мне!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немного неправильно представляете себе понятие "кодировка".

Кодировка - это "не представление последовательности бит при сохранении их в файл". Биты в памяти сохраняются в биты в файле без какого-то перекодирования.

> в какой кодировке она хранится в самой памяти ?

Nodejs, как и многие другие языки высокого уровня, работает со строками не как с "битами в памяти", а как с последовательностью символов (именно символов, не байт!). Все операции со строками (`a = ''; a += 'b';`) принимают на вход строки, и возвращают строки.

Да, где-то внутри при этом в памяти перекладываются байты (которые являются представлением строки в какой-то кодировке). Но при этом в терминах языка и платформы вы работаете со строками именно как со строками, а не с массивами байт.

Так что ответ - неважно в какой, это особенности внутренней реализации строк, и на результат работы со строками это никак не влияет.

> Зачем указывать кодирвоку при открытии текстового файла (Node js) если это просто набор бит?
>
> Зачем при сохранении указывать кодировку? Может чтоб битовая последовательность из памяти сохранилась именно в этой кодировке ?

Строка - это последовательность символов, а не "битовая последовательность из памяти".

Сама по себе необходимость явного преобразования ее в биты в какой-то  конкретной кодировке появляется только при сохранении строки в файл (который является массивом байт на диске), при передаче строки по сети (в виде массива байт), или при попытке явно поработать с ней как с байтами.

Именно поэтому при открытии файла вам приходится указывать кодировку - чтобы явно задать, как преобразовать строку (последовательность символов) в байты файла, и наоборот.

Да, при этом где-то внутри реализации на самом деле происходит перекодирование из "строки в виде байт с использованием кодировки хранения в памяти" в "строку в виде байт, указанных при сохранении файла", но это внутренняя реализация механизма. С точки зрения платформы - вы сохраняете строку (символы) в виде байт на диск.

Comment: Почему если я сохраняю строку в виде hex, то Node js создаст пустой файл где ничего не будет. Hex edit тоже ничего не показал

Comment: Ответьте пожалуйста

Comment: @Letton отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте код - я не совсем представляю, что именно у вас происходит

Comment: fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'hello world', 'hex', function(){});

Comment: @Letton кодировка hex преобразует строку в символьное представление байт в 16-ричной системе счисления. Например она преобразует байт со значением 255 в строку 'FF'. И наоборот. При передаче ей строки, не являющейся символьной записью значений байт в 16-ричной системе (т.е. строки, в которой есть что-то кроме символов 0123456789ABCDEF) - она падает. Ваш пример падает с ошибкой "TypeError: Invalid hex string".

Comment: @Letton он будет работать корректно (писать строку, в которой записаны байты в виде символов, как байты на диск), если в строке именно шестнадцатеричные символы. Например `fs.writeFile('message.txt', '0102AABB', 'hex', function(){});`

Comment: Спасибо! Всё понял

Answer (score 0):

*Зачем указывать кодирвоку при открытии текстового файла (Node js) если это просто набор бит?*

А вот какую букву этот набор бит (лучше, наверное, говорить про набор байт) - вот именно это и определяется кодировкой. Кодировка - это именно соответствие буквы и набору байт. И один и тот же набор может показать совершенно разный текст в зависимости от кодировки.

Comment: я это понимаю, но ответь на другие вопросы